# Spring Boot + JSF static page configurations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf

am getting started with Spring Boot + JSF.
Spring documentation says:

- Spring will automatically load and serve resources inside 
  /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources.
  This is not working for me.
- it is discouraged to use the "webapp" (src/main/webapp) folder.
  But for my static content, it seem to be the only folder thats working with my JSF static page.

see [Spring Boot static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

I have tried these configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class JSFServletConfigs  implements ServletContextInitializer// ,ServletContextAware
{

    @Override // ServletContext initiallization parameters
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        servletContext.setInitParameter("facelets.DEVELOPMENT", "false");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD", "-1");
    }

    @Bean // Registering the FacesServlet.
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet) {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
                FacesInitializer facesInitializer = new FacesInitializer();
                Set<Class<?>> clazz = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
                clazz.add(JSFServletConfigs.class);
                facesInitializer.onStartup(clazz, servletContext);
            }
        };
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("*.xhtml", "*.jsf", "*.html");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jsfViewResolving(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/<sub-folder of any LOCATION>/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");       
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Servlet pre-configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class DefaultServletConfigs extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override // Enabling the default Servlet at path="/"
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    private final String[] LOCATIONS = {"<All my possible locations>"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        if(!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")){
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(LOCATIONS);
        }

        if(!registry.hasMappingForPattern("webjars")){
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
    }
}
```

My Question are:

What am I missing here?

How do I get the flexibility to place my resources in any of the other folders above
(i.e. "/static",  "/public", "/resources", "/META-INF/resources").

Comment: remove @EnableWebMvc but leave Configuration

Comment: removing @EnableWebMv causes no effect.

Comment: you're overriding the addResourceHandler so the default spring boot resource mappings are not added.

Comment: with or without overriding "addResourceHandler" is not helping. I did override to simply make sure that default directories are added (manually). But that did not help.